# how to impliment queue and priority queue in java

Tags: java, queue

I need to get queue and priority queue behaviors in java.Is there any built in data structures already for this? I heard that LinkedList provide queue behaviors.But i was unable to find good example yet?

Answer (score 1):

Interface `java.util.Queue` has many implementations. Those you interested in are `java.util.PriorityQueue` and `java.util.ArrayDeque`.

Don't hesitate to use search. Those topics are extensively covered. Start from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html).